# Yii2 изменение счета в дб по аналогу перечисления

Tags: php, yii2

Controller

```
$update_money = User::findOne($id);
$update_money->money -= $_POST['money'];
$update_money->save();
```

Получается сохранять любые значения в  `$update_money->money`, получается сохранять `$_POST['money']`, не получается вычитать из `$update_money->money` `$_POST['money']`

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял суть вопроса, но если вы хотите изменить только значение колонки `money`, проще использовать метод [updateCounters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#updateCounters()-detail):

```
$update_money = User::findOne($id);
$update_money->updateCounters(['money' => -$_POST['money']]);
```

Comment: спасибо, работает

Comment: `Yii::$app->request->post('money');`

Answer (score 0):

Если я всё так понял, Вам поможет это

```
$update_money = User::findOne($id);
$update_money->money -= (float)$_POST['money'];
$update_money->save();
```